# Metro UI Layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to create layout like Metro UI in android app.

I would like it to look like:

[image]

I was thinking about that and I haven't found solution yet.

Do you have any advice?

P.S. Best way is to have it working programaticaly, without setting whole layout by hand, but if this is not possible, it could be even made by hand.

Comment: hmmmm how about gridview?

Comment: Try to use GridLayout instead GridView.

Comment: @Haresh `GridLayout` available since Api 14

Comment: https://github.com/Comcast/FreeFlow

Comment: @MuhammadBabar `GridLayout` is also included in the **support library v7**. Haresh advice is the best one so far.

Comment: Off topic, Stack Overflow is not designed for recommending tools/external resources as it draws bias answers and spam.

Comment: @EdGeorge A GridLayout **is not** an external tool or resource. So, the question is not off-topic.

Answer (score -1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#1d1d1d">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.75">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="#da532c" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="#00aba9" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2.5">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.1">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:background="#2b5797"
                android:layout_margin="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2.5">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Play"
                android:id="@+id/playbut"
                android:background="#2d89ef"
                android:layout_margin="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.5">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="#00a300" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="#99b433" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="#1e7145" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is that? Please add some explaination.